# Staple through picture page of passport

Tags: passport-renewals

An organisation has stapled my yellow fever certificate onto the photo page of my passport, leaving 2 small holes next to my photo. Could this cause issues when entering a country?

Comment: Can you post a picture? In my opinion from what you describe, no. I have used a raggedy passport with numerous pieces of paper stapled to it and scribbles on some pages without problems.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.